# Using Unity Post Processing v2, how can I apply processing effects to just the UI?

Tags: unity, gui, post-processing

I am using Unity 2018.3 with HDRP 4.9, and Post Processing 2.1.3.

I would like to apply post processing effects (i.e bloom) to the UI only.

I tried the 2 camera approach, but still can't get it working correctly.

I have a post processing volume that is global, and also one that is global but for the UI.  Not sure if this is correct.  Basically I don't want the first processing volume to apply to the UI.

I can apply post processing if I ignore all this second camera stuff and set the canvas to screen space camera.  I then get the effects like bloom applied to the UI.  However, I want to have different post processing for the UI, the global bloom is too much.

First image is the UI Camera.

[image]

Second image is the main camera.

[image]

Third image is the Canvas for the UI.

[image]

Comment: Your setup displayed in the images seems reasonable, though I haven't done this myself. You say "I tried the 2 camera approach, but still can't get it working correctly" - what exact problem did you run into?

Comment: The global processing was still getting applied to the second camera, even with the correct layers set.  Not sure if it's something I am missing, or some issue with the PP stack, though I thought v2 was pretty stable.